# LaTeX: dollar sign vs \( \)

Tags: syntax, latex

Is there any reason to prefer the syntax `\(myformula\)` to the usual `$myformula$` in LaTeX?

**Edit**: The same question was asked, and answered, on [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

LaTeX can catch nesting errors with `\(`...`\)` but in practise there's no real advantage to using them over `$`...`$`. If you *do* use `\(`...`\)`, then make sure to load the `fixltx2e` package to make them robust (i.e., e.g., usable in captions and section headings).

As others have said, on the other hand, `\[`...`\]` should be used instead of `$$`...`$$`.

Answer (score 3):

I read in [1] (German text), that the use of `$$ ... $$` leads to inconsistencies in vertical spaces before and after the formula, which shouldn't happen with `[ ... ]`.

[1] ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/german/l2tabu.pdf (Section 1.6)

Comment: Yes, I consistently use `\[\]` for *display* equations. But here I am concerned with the similar issue for *inline* equations.

Comment: That same document is available in English too: http://mirror.ctan.org/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf (section 1.6 and 3.3).

Answer (score 1):

Only that some editors can't balance $ signs, where they can balance the brackets in the `\(\)` form.  If you have a good editor (and with emacs and auctex mode out there, who doesn't?), then it's not an issue.

Comment: My editor handles $ signs perfectly. I'm just wondering whether there is a difference, since it is often advised to use `\[\]` instead of `$$`.

Answer (score 1):

I use `$formula$` and `$$formula$$`. But sometimes you need to catch the end of the math mode. The thing is that you can catch the begin of the math mode using `\everymath` or `\everydisplay`:

```
\everymath{\color{red}}
```

Unfortunately you can not catch end of the math mode. But if you use `\(` and `\)` you can redefine `\)`:

```
\let\endmath\)% Save \)
\def\){\preendmath \endmath \postendmath}% Override
\def\preendmath{\,(*)}% For example
\def\postendmath{}% Any stuff
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `\everymath` and `\everydisplay`, this might come in handy! But `\everymath` works for me although I use `$formula$`. So the only advantage of `\(\)` is if I ever wanted to do something fancy only at the end of formulas? Why does that syntax exist at all?

Comment: Perhaps another reason is that second `$` in `$formula$` is similar to the first one. To avoid any error with opening or closing `$` you should use `\(\)`. I use $$$s.

Comment: See the answer below about not using `$$`...`$$`; you'll run into problems eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that `$...$` is not technically standard LaTeX, but that `\(` is. Since all latex compilers make use of the underlying TeX engine, this is never an issue, but from a pendant's perspective, there is that difference.

Answer (score -1):

Use `\(...\)` and `\[...\]`.

1. MathJax understands `\(...\)` but not `$...$`. Some day you will want to use MathJax.
2. In 'Find and replace' it is easier to use `\(` and `\)` than `$` and `$`.

   E.g. imagine a situation where you wish to replace each `\(...\)` with `\[...\]` for proof reading purposes.

   I face this thing often, as I create some online courses for my university, and need to shift from LaTeX to HTML and vice versa.