# How to strike out inside LaTeX equations?

Tags: latex, typesetting, strikethrough, mathematical-typesetting

Please see the snippet below and tell me how can I achieve the same strike-out effect as in the main text. I am using the version of LaTeX from the latest Ubuntu repositories.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
The sout tag works perfect in the \sout{main text area} but not inside the equations.
$$
list = [1, \sout{2}, 3, \sout{4}, 5, \sout{6}, 7, \sout{8}, 9, \sout{10}]
$$
Any clue?
\end{document}
```

[Here is LaTeX output](http://tinypic.com/r/2ag976d/5)

Comment: You should not use `$$` in Latex. It is a plain Tex command.

Comment: Furthe to what @Debilski said: there was a little discussion of this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251417/latex-dollar-sign-vs.  I don't regard using $$ as a crime, and I don't think $$ support is going away, but you're better off avoiding it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It looks like the `\sout` doesn't work inside a math env.
You can try doing something like this, which works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
The sout tag works perfect in the \sout{main text area} but not inside the equations.

$list = $[1, \sout{2}, 3, \sout{4}, 5, \sout{6}, 7, \sout{8}, 9, \sout{10}$]$

Any clue?
\end{document}
```

Comment: That does it elegantly. Thanks!

Comment: But package `ulem` changes `\emph{}` to underline.

Comment: from Sara's answer: "... to use strike-out without having ulem redefine how \emph{} works, use `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`".  Thanks Sara!

Answer (score 28):

If anyone's still interested, I just found out about the [cancel package](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex2e/contrib/cancel/cancel.pdf), which allows you to strike your text in math mode in a few different ways. It's not horizontal, though -- only diagonal, which in my case is much better.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this. The \cancelto command is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 12):

Pretty much any non-math-mode command can be used inside mathmode by putting it within a `\text{}` environment, e.g.:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ulem}
\begin{document}
The sout tag works perfect in the \sout{main text area} but not inside the equations.

\[ list = [1, \text{\sout{2}}, 3, \text{\sout{4}}, 5, \text{\sout{6}}, 7, \text{\sout{8}}, 9, \text{\sout{10}}] \]
Any clue?
\end{document}
```

And if you'd like to be able to use strike-out *without* having `ulem` redefine how `\emph{}` works, use `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`.

Answer (score 12):

If you need to keep the strikeout in Math mode (e.g., to keep Math fonts) try:

```
\newcommand{\msout}[1]{\text{\sout{\ensuremath{#1}}}}
```

then

```
$\msout{\mathsf{stuckout}}$
```

you need amsmath and ulem.

(Solution from [here](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=5545).)